# GWT Serialization MyObject java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: gwt, timestamp, rpc, gwt-rpc, serializable

I have defined `MyObject` on client side of my GWT application that implements `IsSerializable`, where `MyObject{String, Timestamp, Timestamp, String}`.

When make a simple rpc (where `AsyncCallback<ArrayList<MyObject>>`), I get the following error:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried with only returning one MyObject (as opposed to an ArrayList) with`AsyncCallback<MyObject>`, which also resulted in the above error.

Finally, I removed the Timestamp properties, so that `MyObject{String, String}`, which worked, leading me to believe that there's a problem with serializing `java.sql.Timestamp`. Can anybody comment on this and advise me on how best to proceed please?

I checked the server logs and found nothing out of the ordinary.

**Edit 1:**
I've tested with `MyObject{Timestamp}` and that also failed.

**Solution so far:**
Quite hacky, moved `MyObject` to shared folder and declared the Timestamps as `transient`, then converted them to longs so that I can create a Timestamp object out of them on client side. Ugly, I know, but it works.

Comment: Did you put the DTO (Data Transer Object) into the shared folder?

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions independently, and neither of them worked. I ended up trying both together (shared folder + long conversion), setting my Timestamps as transient as well. Not quite the elegant solution I was hoping for, but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, so I solved adding a empty contructor in this case in MyObject class

> public MyObject(){}

I hope this could help somebody.

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

I' quite sure serializing a `java.sql.Timestamp` is possible in GWT. If in doubt read up on GWT's serializable types:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes

So I assume your call fails in your method on server-side, not during serialization. Did you try to attach a debugger to see what is happening in your server-side method?

Comment: I did read up on GWT serializable types which is why I'm baffled why this doesn't work (resorting in a desperate SO question :P).  At first it was failing because it was unable to serialize on server side, I thought maybe it was because I was using both Strings and Timestamps, but even after Edit 1, it still wasn't able to serialize on server side. I did attach a debugger and I still got the same error posted in question.